# Getting a non-error warning on all Sequelize validations?

Tags: javascript, validation, warnings, sequelize.js

When any of my Sequelize validations are triggered I receive a `non-error` warning in the console. Here is an example of one field's validations:

```
company_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
        allowNull: true,
        validate: {
            not: {args: [badWordsList.regex], msg: "Try to keep the profanity to a minimum."},
            len: {args: [0, 100], msg: "Your company name cannot be greater than 100 characters long."}
        }
}
```

The warning is a stack trace and looks like:

```
Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object String]
at /Users/<user>/Documents/Webstorm Projects/<project>/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:193:33
at /Users/<user>/Documents/Webstorm Projects/<project>/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3073:15
...
```

I have tried updating and upgrading npm but have not had any luck resolving these warnings. Everything works fine otherwise. Is there any way to either prevent or suppress these warnings? I will include more of the stack trace if need be. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the code of `instance-validator.js`, it seems that it throws the `msg` as an error:

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/instance-validator.js#L275

`sequelize` uses `Bluebird` promise library, and it shows the warning at the end:

https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/docs/docs/warning-explanations.md#warning-a-promise-was-rejected-with-a-non-error

You can ignore the warning.

Comment: Thanks for the insight into what is causing this, I feel comfortable ignoring the warnings now.